# how do we remake our query to delete valuers from Price.Present that absent in [Goods].Remnant?

Tags: ms-access

**we have price table and  goods table in access
we need to make query to delete all price values
from table price that absent in table goods and leave all prices in table price that exist in table goods.

this code only update values how do we remake our program
(delete valuers from Price.Present that absent in [Goods].Remnant  )?**

```
UPDATE Price INNER JOIN Goods ON [Price].Article = [Goods].Article SET Price.Present = [Goods].Remnant;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
DELETE * FROM Price
WHERE Price.Present NOT IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT Remnant FROM Goods
);
```

This will delete all records from Price where the values in Price.Present are not found in Goods.Remnant.

**WARNING**: You should test this as a SELECT query first to confirm that the records it returns are the correct ones you want to delete. Here is the same query but with SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM Price
WHERE Price.Present NOT IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT Remnant FROM Goods
);
```